More than one custom value accessor matches form control unspecified name attributes NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR
More than one custom value accessor matches form control unspecified name attributes NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR
I am created two directives for input fields one checkbox true or false instead of 0 or 1 . another directive option value  I need number not string
Directive1 : 
@Directive({selector: DI_1, 
providers: [     
{
provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
useExisting: forwardRef(() => Directive1),
multi: true     
}   
]})


Directive2 : 
@Directive({selector: DI_2,
 providers: [     
{       provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, 
        useExisting: forwardRef(() => Directive2),
        multi: true     
}   
]})

if I am removing onthe providers. it is working fine.I need both directive How to resolve on angular

Try not use providers else inject the ngControl in the constructor in the way
@Directive({selector: DI_1, 
//remove the providers
/*providers: [     
  {
   provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
   useExisting: forwardRef(() => Directive1),
   multi: true     
  }   
]
*/
})
export class Directive1
{
  constructor(public ngControl: NgControl) {
    if (ngControl) {
        ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
    }
  }
  ...
}

BTW, we can use  some like
<input type="checkbox" [ngModel]="variable==1" 
                       (ngModelChange)="variable=$event?1:0/>
//or
<input type="checkbox" [ngModel]="variable=='1'" 
                       (ngModelChange)="variable=$event?'1':0/>

With reactive forms
<input type="checkbox" [ngModel]="control.value==1" 
                       (ngModelChange)="control.setValue($event?1:0)"
                       [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}"
/>
//or
<input type="checkbox" [ngModel]="control.value=='1'" 
                       (ngModelChange)="control.setValue($event?'1':0)"
                       [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}"
/>

with
get control()
{
   return this.form.get('my control')
}

